# How to convert table to a responsive layout using flexbox and Bootstrap 4.1?

Tags: css, html-table, sass, flexbox, responsive

I have a table in which I would like to adjust the layout on smaller screens.  I have fiddled with this for the entire day, and I am stuck.  I am unsure if the `<table>` format is the way to go, or if I need to only use `<div>` flexbox?  I am using Bootstrap 4.1, but the solution could be custom CSS (or SCSS)

The format is as follows:

On larger screens - standard table layout with columns 1 and 2 will ellipse

```
+---------------------------+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

On smaller screens the headers disappear and columns 1&2, 3&4 wrap, columns 5&6 are hidden, and column 7 remains

```
+---+---+---+
| A | C | G |
| B | D |   |
+---+---+---+
| A | C | G |
| B | D |   |
+---+---+---+
| A | C | G |
| B | D |   |
+---+---+---+
```

I also have a JSFiddle started here... [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/burtonrhodes/aq9Laaew/263636/)

Comment: This guy did something similar. Maybe his work helps you to transform your table with flexbox.https://codepen.io/vasansr/pen/jWazPM. Here you can find his complete article about it: https://hashnode.com/post/really-responsive-tables-using-css3-flexbox-cijzbxd8n00pwvm53sl4l42cx

Comment: yes - I did see that solution during my search process, but that solution requires that you define/hard code column widths at certain media query views.  I was hoping to avoid hard coding any width to make the solution completely responsive.

Comment: Perhaps that's really the only way you can pull this off?